# Put pattern in different column

Tags: text-processing

I wanted to print the pattern found each time in the next column and not in the next line like with grep command.

for exemple in big `file 1`
When I do `grep -A3 "coordinate" file1>>file2` I get this:

```
coordinates
 X1 Y1 Z1
 X2 Y2 Z2
 X3 Y3 Z3
coordinates
 X1 Y1 Z1
 X2 Y2 Z2
 X3 Y3 Z3
```

But I want to get this:

```
coordinates   coordinates
 X1 Y1 Z1       X1 Y1 Z1
 X2 Y2 Z2       X2 Y2 Z2
 X3 Y3 Z3       X3 Y3 Z3
```

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -v x=3 '/coordinates/ {
    for(recNr=0; recNr<=x; recNr++){
        data[recNr]=(data[recNr]==""?"": data[recNr] OFS) $0
        if(recNr<x) getline
    }
}
END { for(recNr=0; recNr<=x; recNr++) print data[recNr] }' infile
```

---

In the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), with `-v variableName` we can define an awk variable, which we have defined one to pass the number of lines after the mactehed line we want to capture too.

The `/regex/` syntax is meant to match the desired *regex* against the current processing record by the awk.

we then used a for-loop to concatenate every matched line and 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> lines after the match each into single line in appending mode where each of those groups has an identical referece key value as the *recNr*; with that *`getline`* statement we are reading the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> lines after the matched *coordinates* line.

then at the END, we are printing all those records which already has joined into one again using a for-loop to travers in the order and print.

---

If you wanted to apply some beauty width in the output, try:

```
awk -v x=3 -v width=15 '/coordinates/ {
    for(recNr=0; recNr<=x; recNr++){
        data[recNr]=(data[recNr]==""?"": data[recNr] OFS) sprintf("%*-s", width, $0)
        if(recNr<x) getline
    }
}
END { for(recNr=0; recNr<=x; recNr++) print data[recNr] }' infile
```

Output:

```
coordinates     coordinates
 X1 Y1 Z1        X1 Y1 Z1
 X2 Y2 Z2        X2 Y2 Z2
 X3 Y3 Z3        X3 Y3 Z3
```

---

*Note: this won't cover the case where if you had another `coordinates` lines within those 3 next lines.*

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk and assuming your data isn't too huge to all fit in memory at once:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    numLines = 4
}
/coordinates/ {
    numBlocks++
    lineNr = 0
}
++lineNr <= numLines {
    blocks[numBlocks,lineNr] = $0
}
END {
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        for ( blockNr=1; blockNr<=numBlocks; blockNr++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", blocks[blockNr,lineNr], (blockNr<numBlocks ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
coordinates coordinates
 X1 Y1 Z1    X1 Y1 Z1
 X2 Y2 Z2    X2 Y2 Z2
 X3 Y3 Z3    X3 Y3 Z3
```